# Bonita ui designer forms are not working with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, bonita

I have tried simple process variable example given at link http://community.bonitasoft.com/project/process-variable-example using BonitaBPMCommunity-7.3.1-Tomcat-7.0.67. Its working well in bonita studio. I have made .bar file of process and upload it in process tab in bonita tomcat bundle portal. But neither its fetching process variable values nor passing to next Step Step1/Step2. Process variable example is working fine with default h2 database configuration but when i configured tomcat bundle with Postgres database its not working with bonita ui forms. I have used database connection instructions given at link http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/?page=tomcat-bundle . There is no error in log file for postgres but when i run process it gives error at Step2 that

2016-11-23 08:32:49.078 +0500 INFO: org.restlet.Component.BonitaRestletApplication Error while validating expected inputs Explanations: Expected input [newVariableValue] is missing

[image]

[image]

Bonita Log file:

```
2016-11-23 08:20:27.182 +0500 INFO: org.bonitasoft.platform.setup.PlatformSetup System property org.bonitasoft.platform.setup.folder is set to C:\Users\User\Documents\BonitaBPMCommunity-7.3.1-Tomcat-7.0.67\setup
2016-11-23 08:20:27.226 +0500 INFO: org.bonitasoft.platform.setup.PlatformSetup Connected to 'postgres' database with url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bonitaengine' with user: 'bonitaengine'
2016-11-23 08:20:27.229 +0500 INFO: org.bonitasoft.platform.setup.ScriptExecutor configuration for Database vendor: postgres
2016-11-23 08:20:27.415 +0500 INFO: org.bonitasoft.platform.setup.PlatformSetup Platform is already created. Nothing to do.
2016-11-23 08:20:27.627 +0500 INFO: org.bonitasoft.engine.EngineInitializer Initializing Bonita Engine...
2016-11-23 08:20:27.628 +0500 INFO: org.bonitasoft.engine.EngineInitializer Initializing Spring context...
2016-11-23 08:20:35.613 +0500 WARNING: org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory HHH000233: Scoping types to session factory org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@7423bec4 after already scoped org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@44308726
2016-11-23 08:20:41.867 +0500 INFO: org.bonitasoft.engine.EngineInitializer Starting platform...
2016-11-23 08:20:48.509 +0500 INFO: org.bonitasoft.engine.EngineInitializer Platform started successfully
2016-11-23 08:20:48.510 +0500 INFO: org.bonitasoft.engine.EngineInitializer Initialization of Bonita Engine done! ( took 20882ms)
2016-11-23 08:21:39.163 +0500 INFO: org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/bonita] RestletServlet: [Restlet] ServerServlet: component class is null
2016-11-23 08:21:39.533 +0500 INFO: org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/bonita] RestletServlet: [Restlet] Attaching application: org.bonitasoft.web.rest.server.BonitaRestletApplication@5efff180 to URI: /bonita/API
2016-11-23 08:21:39.557 +0500 INFO: org.restlet.Component.BonitaRestletApplication Starting org.bonitasoft.web.rest.server.BonitaRestletApplication application
2016-11-23 08:21:54.415 +0500 SEVERE: org.bonitasoft.console.common.server.login.credentials.LoginDatastore Error while logging in the engine API.
2016-11-23 08:24:47.160 +0500 INFO: org.restlet.Component.BonitaRestletApplication Error while validating expected inputs
Explanations:
Expected input [myInput] is missingExpected input [mysInput] is missingExpected input [myMultipleDocumentsContract] is missingExpected input [myMultipleDocumentsDeleteContract] is missingExpected input [brnchInput] is missingExpected input [secInput] is missing
2016-11-23 08:29:18.201 +0500 INFO: org.restlet.Component.BonitaRestletApplication Error while validating expected inputs
Explanations:
Expected input [newVariableValue] is missing
2016-11-23 08:32:49.078 +0500 INFO: org.restlet.Component.BonitaRestletApplication Error while validating expected inputs
Explanations:
Expected input [newVariableValue] is missing
```

catalina Server log file:

```
2016-11-23 08:20:16.487 +0500 INFO: org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;E:\DevProgramm\maven\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell;.
2016-11-23 08:20:17.317 +0500 INFO: org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
2016-11-23 08:20:17.353 +0500 INFO: org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
2016-11-23 08:20:17.361 +0500 INFO: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina Initialization processed in 2175 ms
2016-11-23 08:20:17.362 +0500 INFO: bitronix.tm.integration.tomcat55.BTMLifecycleListener Starting Bitronix Transaction Manager
2016-11-23 08:20:17.396 +0500 INFO: bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager Bitronix Transaction Manager version 2.1.3
2016-11-23 08:20:17.400 +0500 INFO: bitronix.tm.Configuration JVM unique ID: 
2016-11-23 08:20:17.458 +0500 WARNING: bitronix.tm.journal.DiskJournal active log file is unclean, did you call BitronixTransactionManager.shutdown() at the end of the last run?
2016-11-23 08:20:17.464 +0500 INFO: bitronix.tm.resource.ResourceLoader reading resources configuration from C:\Users\User\Documents\BonitaBPMCommunity-7.3.1-Tomcat-7.0.67/conf/bitronix-resources.properties
2016-11-23 08:20:21.822 +0500 INFO: bitronix.tm.recovery.Recoverer recovery committed 0 dangling transaction(s) and rolled back 0 aborted transaction(s) on 2 resource(s) [jdbc/BusinessDataDSXA, jdbc/bonitaDSXA] (restricted to serverId 'bonita-tomcat-btm-node0')
2016-11-23 08:20:21.917 +0500 INFO: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService Starting service Catalina
2016-11-23 08:20:21.918 +0500 INFO: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
2016-11-23 08:20:21.945 +0500 INFO: org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\User\Documents\BonitaBPMCommunity-7.3.1-Tomcat-7.0.67\conf\Catalina\localhost\bonita.xml
2016-11-23 08:20:48.292 +0500 INFO: org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2016-11-23 08:20:48.293 +0500 INFO: org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.1 created.
2016-11-23 08:20:48.295 +0500 INFO: org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin Registering Quartz shutdown hook.
2016-11-23 08:20:48.300 +0500 INFO: org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) 'QuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
NOT STARTED.
Currently in standby mode.
Number of jobs executed: 0
Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 5 threads.
Using job-store 'org.bonitasoft.engine.scheduler.impl.BonitaJobStoreCMT' - which supports persistence. and is not clustered.

2016-11-23 08:20:48.302 +0500 INFO: org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler JobFactory set to: org.bonitasoft.engine.scheduler.impl.TransactionalSimpleJobFactory@26246754
2016-11-23 08:20:48.469 +0500 INFO: org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2016-11-23 08:20:52.145 +0500 INFO: org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\User\Documents\BonitaBPMCommunity-7.3.1-Tomcat-7.0.67\conf\Catalina\localhost\bonita.xml has finished in 30,201 ms
2016-11-23 08:20:52.148 +0500 INFO: org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig Deploying web application directory C:\Users\User\Documents\BonitaBPMCommunity-7.3.1-Tomcat-7.0.67\webapps\manager
2016-11-23 08:20:52.324 +0500 INFO: org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\User\Documents\BonitaBPMCommunity-7.3.1-Tomcat-7.0.67\webapps\manager has finished in 177 ms
2016-11-23 08:20:52.325 +0500 INFO: org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig Deploying web application directory C:\Users\User\Documents\BonitaBPMCommunity-7.3.1-Tomcat-7.0.67\webapps\ROOT
2016-11-23 08:20:52.462 +0500 INFO: org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\User\Documents\BonitaBPMCommunity-7.3.1-Tomcat-7.0.67\webapps\ROOT has finished in 137 ms
2016-11-23 08:20:52.465 +0500 INFO: org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
2016-11-23 08:20:52.500 +0500 INFO: org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
2016-11-23 08:20:52.503 +0500 INFO: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina Server startup in 35140 ms
```

there are 81 tables created in bonita databsase in postgres.

Comment: Can you share your diagram .bos file? I think you have some incoherence between your process contract and data sent by the form.

Comment: .bos file is given at ink https://github.com/Bonitasoft-Community/process-variable-example

Comment: variable is accessible only when user is admin . otherwise processvariable is not accesible to simple user

Answer (score 0):

Actually the fact that variables is only available to administrator is a know limitation. It's documented in the REST API extension [readme file](http://community.bonitasoft.com/project/process-variable-example) under the "Known limitation" section.

You can change such behavior by customizing dynamic-permissions-checks.properties. Refer to [REST API authorization documentation](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/?page=rest-api-authorization) for more information.